# Failed to add plugin to the panel, no running instance of xfce4-panel was found

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, kubuntu, kde, xfce

I have a fresh install of xubuntu 16.04.3. I logged in with xfce once to make sure everything was working, and then I installed kubuntu-desktop.

But when I log in to kde/plasma, I get an error box pop up:

```
Error
Failed to add a plugin to the panel
No running instance of xfce4-panel was found
```

I have tried deleting my `.cache` and `.config`, but this error still appears every time I start a kde session. It does not appear if I start an xfce session.

I also tried logging in to xfce and logging out with "save session' unticked, but this hasn't fixed the problem either.

What else could be causing xfce plugins to start in kde?

Answer (score 1):

`ps aux | grep xfce` showed the following process:

```
/usr/bin/xfce4-panel --add=launcher /home/simon/.config/autostart-scripts/xscreensaver.desktop
```

Once I deleted `~/.config/autostart-scripts/xscreensaver.desktop` the error stopped appearing.