# How to undo "Do not ask again" for running executable files in Dolphin (Kubuntu)?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, dolphin

I am using Kubuntu 20.04, but the question probably also applies to older versions.

When clicking on a .sh file in Dolphin (File Manager), I got a pop-up screen with the following text:

```
What do you wish to do with this executable file?
☐ Do not ask again
Open Execute Cancel
```

I choose "Execute" and checked "Do not ask again".
How do I undo this, so I get the pop-up screen again?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Settings > Configure Dolphin > General > Confirmations > When opening an executable file

It may not show the state correctly but on applying changes it should set the state to the selected value.

Comment: I think the change is written to `~/.config/kiorc` in the section titled [Executable scripts]. Though changing it via the GUI as you've explained is the way to do it.

Comment: Thank you! Reported the problem of "open" value not being detected here: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=421294